# How can I fit a triangle to 3 lines?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, kinematics

[image]

I have 3 simple straight lines, 2 are nearly horizontal and parallel and 1 is nearly vertical (blue in the diagram).

I have a triangle (orange) which is fixed in shape by the lengths of its 3 sides.

There will be only one postion of the triangle where the 3 verticies are directly on the 3 lines. How is this calculated?

The calculation needs to be done frequently for slightly varying line lengths of the triangle.

The lengths of the blue lines are not important but typically the variations expected would fit in the short distances shown.

It is only the 3 contacts condition that is required, the triangle is not allowed to rotate / move way from this.

I would like to know the 3 contact points on the 3 blue lines.

Comment: Could you add an image to clarify your situation? I'm having difficulty understanding what you mean

Comment: Can you also say how your triangle and lines are specified --- do you have equations for the lines, with the first two having the form Ax + By + C = 0, where $|B| >> |A|$, and the third having such an equation with $|A| >> |B|$? Is your triangle specified with the three edge-lengths? The locations of the three vertices? Some other way? And when you say "a perfect fit", do you mean "with one vertex on each of the three lines"? (Presumably you mean "by a translation and small rotation", right?)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I added a pic. The blue lines are the fixed lines I would like to fit the orange triangle to, the orange triangle is known by the length of the 3 sides, it is constantly changing by a small amount so the points at which it touches the 3 blue lines needs to be frequently recalculated

Comment: What is the perfect fit? There are infinite triangles that would fit the bill. Each pair of three points defines another triangle.

Comment: This is a model of a mechanical system. The orange triangle is rigid. With the mechanics, the orange triangle fits only in one place. It would have to change shape even if slightly to fit anywhere else.

Comment: If the orange triangle slides on the top 2 blue lines, the lower left point will rotate away from its blue line

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add relevant details if the triangle is rigid, what size/shape information is given (three side lengths?). Also, do the lines extend to infinity, or have terminal points? NOTE: The comments isn't a good place to leave the crucial info needed to answer your question.

Comment: What about a situation where the triangle is allowed to rotate from the configuration and it will lose contact with the lines if do so? Is there a requirement that the triangle is held there _statically_. What I am saying is if the three (normal) contact forces meet at a single point, the triangle will have 1 degree of freedom, instead of 0 DOF. Is that acceptable?

Comment: apologies just clarified the main description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Not a solution (yet).*

This is a hard problem with strong hints of mechanism synthesis and rigid body kinematics.

### Ideal Solution

I think what you are looking for is this

[image: fig1]

Three fixed lines form a triangle **ABC** in space. Let's call these the walls. A smaller rigid body triangle **PQR** is inscribed inside the walls. The sides if the inscribed triangle are known as $\ell_{PQ}$, $\ell_{QR}$ and $\ell_{RP}$.

### Statics

In this ideal solution, each contact point **P**, **Q** and **R** has a normal vector (red dashed arrows below) describing the direction of where contact forces could develop.

[image: fig2]

Each arrow is *perpendicular* to the wall in contact and goes through the respective contact point.

Where any two these arrows meet, for example at **G**<sub>PQ</sub> above, it designates *the instant center of rotation* for the side of the triangle connecting the two contact points (side **PQ** here).

This means that points **P** and **Q** both are going to slide along the wall when the rigid body is rotated about **G**<sub>PQ</sub>.

**This is a kinematic condition to maintain contact with the walls at any time**

We exploit this geometry to nudge the body in order to make all three points contact the walls

### Kinematics

Now imagine a situation where point **Q** is not quite in contact yet

[image: fig3]

We can rotate the about the point **G**<sub>RP</sub> where the side **RP** is going to slide along their walls in order to bring **Q** closer to its wall. Draw radiuses from **G**<sub>RP</sub> to **P**, **Q** and **R** and show the direction of motion for each triangle corner in blue arrows above.

Now if you rotate by a finite angle $\Delta \theta > 0$ the points are going to follow little arcs, and not lines. This means that yes point **Q** is going to get closer to the wall, but points **P** and **R** are actually going to come off the wall by a tiny amount.

This means that in practice you will have to go around each point, doing rotation such as that point meets the wall. Then rinse and repeat with each point on the triangle.

At some point, you will be *close enough* to the wall to have a satisfactory answer, but you will never get the *exact* position where all three points are going to be on each wall.

Please note that if all three contact normals come together through the same point, then the body is not stable as any torque applied would twist the part and it would just happily slide along the walls.

Comment: Thanks very much. I am slightly reassured that this is a hard problem after the time I have spent on it! As I have to provide a solution, while I was hoping for a direct method, I have gone in the direction of an iterative approach as you suggest. Although slower, more CPU intense, and imprecise, I think this will provide a good enough solution.

Comment: This is a task best suited for a CAD package. Nevertheless, you can try an optimization routine with the triangle having 3DOF (point position and orientation angle) and then 3 cost functions as the distance to the walls. You need a non-linear optimization solver to do this, iteratively.

Comment: I got it working well enough. I define my 3 lines, my 3 points I would like to be in contact with them,  and an origin for the rotation. I have a function that provides a reasonable estimate for position and rotation error by looking at the perpendicular distances from the lines to the points. This transforms the 3 points and I can then loop and do it again. I am finding that with my system (approx 1 m square) I can get an answer within target accuracy (0.0001mm, a tenth of a micron) with only 10 iterations approx. I'm surprised by how well this works. Many thanks for your input with this.

Comment: Nonlinear optimization solvers are good at finding the path of the least effort to the solution. Glad you got it working. Do you want me to update my answer with this methodology? You can accept the answer if it was helpful to you.